# No Entity Found (Developer Datastore Console)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is anyone else having an issue with a lot of their datastore entities being "un-editable" in the Developers Console?

I always get this error when clicking on an entity ID:

> We could not find an entity with namespace: "{NAMESPACE}", kind: "{KIND}", and identifier "id={ID}"

[image]

[Google Issue Reported](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11847&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log)

Comment: I have the same problem several times. At some point i cannot see the entity list either. Personally I use the old console (https://appengine.google.com/) for datastore editing. The new one seems to more unstable than the old one.

Comment: Ahh good idea. For the time being, I'll do that. Thanks @DevilingMaster

Comment: That's an issue going around since the updated the new console, since not everyone if affected but a bunch of us are so you are not alone. As Devilin master said just use the old school console for now until the fix it.

Comment: @jirungaray Will do man, thanks for letting me know I'm not alone.